# Can’t access CSS files via XAMPP localhost setup

Tags: apache-http-server, php, css

I'm trying to run a `localhost` version of a website and the stylesheet for the site in inexplicably inaccessible to the browser.

Some Basics:

- **OS**: Windows
- **Browser**: Chrome (have also tried Edge)
- **Editing environement**: Eclipse
- **XAMPP**: v3.2.4

This is how I'm calling the CSS file.

```
<link href='/style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
```

I'm updating some PHP on a site that is fairly old, the site was using PHP 5.5.9 and we want to update it to the latest PHP (off the top of my head it's 7.2.3). In doing this I want to modify the site code locally before changes are applied to our server. The server is Linux based so that is one fundamental dependency that is different from my local environment.

A problem that I've run into is that the CSS file returns either error 404 or error 403 if the location `https://localhost/style.css` is put into the chrome browser. It seems that this happens if the path to the CSS file is wrong or the permissions to the file are not readable. I've tried converting the path of the CSS to an absolute path, I've checked the permissions and the system has all the read capability it needs.

I thought the problem might have been with the actual path to the CSS, but it's in the same location as the all the PHP files which are loading in just fine, whether using relative root location or document root. Note, the document root is now a subfolder with the HTML docs that contains all the website files for the page.

And please note that I've not modified this CSS file at all. It's the same as the one running on the live site.

Comment: Does this website have an `.htaccess` file that might be rewriting URLs? Also, I know you are on Windows, but if you somehow can run Curl from the command line run this command to see how the URL might be redirected or resolved: `curl -I http://localhost/style.css`. Additionally I would recommend using Firefox for debugging since it’s not as forceful in caching data—or enforcing HTTPS—as other browsers such as Chrome.

Comment: Is the CSS file really on the root folder? Or in the same folder as the HTML / PHP file?
In that case the HREF should be ./style.css or just style.css

Comment: On the page that is failing press F12 in your browser to see the developers window and look at the console tab to see if there are any errors.

Comment: For the curl command the output was as follows : HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Thu, 27 Jun 2019 13:19:10 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.39 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1c PHP/7.3.6
Vary: accept-language,accept-charset
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Language: en

Comment: I also tried curl -I https://localhost/rebat.css. and got : curl: (77) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: SEC_E_UNTRUSTED_ROOT (0x80090325) - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.

Comment: I'll use Firefox if that is recommended. there is a .htaccess file with RewriteRule ^style.css$ /style-css.php [L]. I'm not sure what this means though. I'm going to look into what this is supposed to do, because it sounds like what JakeGould is talking about.

Comment: Regarding Shifty, I've tried both versions of the href and the .css is in the document root folder.

Comment: Dave, these are the errors I get when using F12 on the .css file page Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.
style.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found). On the actual page that is trying to apply the .css I get this : GET http://localhost/style.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
index.php:1 Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

[Giacomo1968](https://superuser.com/questions/1453326/can-t-access-css-files-via-xampp-localhost-setup#comment2192303_1453326)’s comment gets the credit for the fix. the line `RewriteRule ^style.css$ /style-css.php [L]` was removed from `.htaccess`.

I'm still vague on what that line was for, there was no `style-css.php` file in the project root. This allowed the CSS to be viewed.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Try `<link href="style.css" media="all" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />`